# How Customize Wndows Server ISO Image For Install An Exe File After Install Windows

Tags: windows, installation, iso-image

There is an iso here :
[Virtio Win Guest Tools](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_VirtIO_Drivers)
This iso contains some folders and 64 bit exe file for install Virtio Win Guest Tools.
I have **windows sewrver 2022** iso image.
Now how can i inject that iso package to windows image and tell that iso to install that package after windows installation?

Comment: Do you wish for a Windows ISO that contains the VirtIO drivers?

Comment: Yes, I want to use irtIO driver from https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_VirtIO_Drivers | No other web sites.

Comment: Also i want to learn how can i add a program to windows iso and tell that iso install that program after installation. The point of this issue is program is not an alone exe file and it contains some other files and folders.

Comment: @Anahita - That would be a separate question from this question how to create your own Windows image that includes preinstalled applications.  However, that entire process while not difficult is fairly complex. So you would have to have a specific question about a specific step in that process, not simply a question about how to do the entire process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting the VirtIO drivers into a Windows ISO is discussed in the
Proxmox article
[Windows guests - build ISOs including VirtIO drivers](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_guests_-_build_ISOs_including_VirtIO_drivers):

> Using [Paravirtualized Block Drivers for Windows](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Paravirtualized_Block_Drivers_for_Windows) can dramatically improve Windows guest performance but installing them can be a bit of a fuss. This Tutorial shows you how you can inject all VirtIO drivers into all of your Windows install ISOs in one step using Windows® Automated Installation Kit and some batch files. This makes it really easy to deploy Windows with the most efficient hardware/driver configuration.